# Can we write trigger on LoginHistory object

Tags: trigger, standard-objects, history-tracking

I want to copy login history data in custom object when new entry added to login history. If trigger is not possible then is there workaround for the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create a trigger on `LoginHistory` object. But as workaround you can create a [scheduled apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) which will query `LoginHistory` objects

```
global class CopyLoginHistory implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<LoginHistory> loginHistories = [SELECT ApiType,
                                                    ApiVersion,
                                                    Application,
                                                    Browser,
                                                    ClientVersion,
                                                    Id,
                                                    LoginTime,
                                                    LoginType,
                                                    LoginUrl,
                                                    Platform,
                                                    SourceIp,
                                                    Status,
                                                    UserId
                                            FROM LoginHistory
                                            WHERE LoginTime <: System.now()
                                            AND LoginTime >: System.now().addMinutes(-1)];
        if ( !loginHistories.isEmpty()) {
            List<LoginHistoryCopy__c> lhc = new List<LoginHistoryCopy__c>();
            for (LoginHistory lh: loginHistories) {
                lhc.add(new LoginHistoryCopy__c(ApiType__c       = ApiType ,
                                                ApiVersion__c    = ApiVersion ,
                                                Application__c   = Application ,
                                                Browser__c       = Browser ,
                                                ClientVersion__c = ClientVersion ,
                                                Id__c            = Id ,
                                                LoginTime__c     = LoginTime ,
                                                LoginType__c     = LoginType ,
                                                LoginUrl__c      = LoginUrl ,
                                                Platform__c      = Platform ,
                                                SourceIp__c      = SourceIp ,
                                                Status__c        = Status ,
                                                UserId__c        = UserId
                ));
            }
            insert lhc;
        }
   }
}
```

and copy these records to custom object

Comment: But in this case we can get real time data. right?

Comment: @pornima What is the reason for copying this data?

Comment: If the user don't have manage user permission he can't access login history data. I want to show login history details to users who don't have manage user permission. I just want to copy login history in custom object and give access to that custom object.

Comment: @pornima and why do you need a real time data? Is it critical data for your users?

Comment: @pornima Scheduled apex has limit in 250.000 executions per 25-hour period. Running scheduled apex every minute is required 1440 executions per 24h.