# Trigger on LoginHistory isn't possible - what are the possible solutions?

Tags: apex

I would like to be notified via email whenever a Salesforce user tries to login but their effort has the status of 'Failed: API security token required' logged against the LoginHistory record.

I'm aware it isn't possible to write triggers or workflows on LoginHistory. So I was thinking of copying [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66827/can-we-write-trigger-on-loginhistory-object) (scheduled apex), and then calling the Messaging.SingleMessage method to send the email notification.

Are there any reasons why this approach wouldn't work? Or is there a better approach, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem with this approach. Just remember that you have a limit on how many emails you can send to email addresses, so it is much better to send any such emails to a specific user.

You might consider implementing `Batchable` as well. The `system.scheduleBatch` method is quite useful, and I find it much easier to chain batches using this method. Then you can just run it every 15 minutes or so.

```
public with sharing class SecurityTokenRequiredBatch implements Database.Batchable, Schedulable
{
    @TestVisible static Boolean chainBatches = true;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT ... FROM LoginHistory WHERE Status = '...'
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<LoginHistory> scope)
    {
        // send email
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        if (chainBatchas) system.scheduleBatch(this, 15);
    }
}
```